# Remove "xmlns" prefix from xmlTree in R

Tags: xml, r

I need to translate R output directly into XML following a specific schema ("someLocalFile.xsd"). Using the 'XML' package, is it possible to remove the "xmlns" prefix from a namespace so I can have the following:

#### Desired Output

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Assessment xmlns:xsi="http://website.com" xsi:schemaLocation="someLocalFile.xsd">
<stock>10</stock>
<stock>20</stock>
<stock>30</stock>
</Assessment>
```

#### Current Output

```
...
<Assessment xmlns:xsi="http://website.com" xmlns:xsi:schemaLocation="someLocalFile.xsd">
...
```

My code:

```
library(XML)
#
z = xmlTree("Assessment", namespaces = list(xsi = "http://website.com",
                                        xsi:schemaLocation = "someLocalFile.xsd"),
        doc = newXMLDoc())
#
z$addNode("stock", value = 10)
z$addNode("stock", value = 20)
z$addNode("stock", value = 30)
z$closeTag()
#
cat(saveXML(z))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xsi:schemaLocation should be an attribute, not a namespace definition.
So

```
z = xmlTree("Assessment", 
             namespaces = c(xsi = "http://website.com"),
             attrs = c('xsi:schemaLocation' = "someLocalFile.xsd"),
             doc = newXMLDoc())
```

will do what you want.
(You can ignore the warning about the missing namespace definition.)

Comment: Thank you Duncan! Works perfectly. As the code will be run in batch, is there a good way to avoid the namespace definition warning (other than suppressWarnings() )? Thanks again for the XML package, it's great.